# Issues while executing google perfkit

Tags: performance, python-2.7, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run google's perfkit performance tool on GCP as described on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker. After getting the GCP account and project id, when I am trying to run the perfkit from my personal machine, I encountered following error:

```
Generating temporary directory at  /tmp/perfkitbenchmarker\run_4c0ee849
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkb.py", line 21, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main())
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\perfkitbenchmarker\pkb.py", line 358, in Main
    return RunBenchmarks()
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\perfkitbenchmarker\pkb.py", line 291, in RunBenchmarks
    ConfigureLogging()
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\perfkitbenchmarker\pkb.py", line 167, in ConfigureLogging
    vm_util.GenTempDir()
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\perfkitbenchmarker\vm_util.py", line 88, in GenTempDir
    create_process = subprocess.Popen(create_cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

There seems to be issue with creating a temporary directory, but should I go and create this directory?
How should I run this tool from my personal machine?
Personal machine configuration on which I am trying to run the perfkit:
OS: Windows7; Python:2.7
**NOTE: I am running the commands in administrator mode.**

Comment: Even after changing the temp directory I got the same directory: Generating temporary directory at  \tmp\perfkitbenchmarker\run_172a0d1c gave the same error.

Comment: Looks like this bug has been [reported](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker/issues/188) by you and a solution has been found. Could you share the solution here so others have could benefit from.

Comment: I didn't got the solution, so I migrated to Linux. It seems, code for perfkit has not been tested on windows environment. It is working fine for Linux machine.